Understanding the Execution Plan Discrepancy in a MySQL Query Involving Left Joins and Filtering
I wrote a SQL query to fetch all movies and, if present, include the name 'Brad Pitt' for movies where he's a cast member. The query is as follows:
select m.title,  p_cast.person_name 
From movie m left join (
      movie_cast m_cast join person p_cast on m_cast.person_id = p_cast.person_id and 
      p_cast.person_name = 'Brad Pitt'
 ) on m.movie_id = m_cast.movie_id 

I expected the execution plan in MySQL Workbench to show that the database left-joins the movie table with the result of the join between movie_cast and person. However, the plan suggests a different sequence: it appears to join movie with movie_cast first, and only then does it join with person where the filter for 'Brad Pitt' is applied. Here is the plan.
.
If this interpretation of the execution plan is accurate, I'm trying to understand where the left join is actually being implemented. If the join sequence is as described, I expected that rows including cast members other than Brad Pitt would be retained, which is not the case.
Does the execution plan really represent what's happening internally (and if so, how to make sense of the execution flow?), or is there a potential error in how it's being displayed or interpreted?

Are you gettting unexpected results? If so, what are those unexpected results? If not, then what's wrong with the execution plan?

The results are correct, but I can't comprehend the query plan. Suppose the first join returns 20 cast members for a movie. Each of these 20 tuples would then be left-joined with the person table, and all 20 tuples should be retained. However, that is not what happens. So, are the tuples joined in a way that differs from what is shown in the query plan?

The 2nd join is not a left join, so why would it retain the 19 rows that are filtered out? Execution plans are always simplified for human consumption. These do not contain all fine details as to what's going on in the background.

If the second join is not a left join, than all movie tuples would be filtered out for non-Brad Pitt movies.  An

I agree that the query plan omits what is happening in the background. That is exactly my point. In fact, I suspect that the real plan tree is not left-side oriented, as illustrated in the picture. I just want to be sure of that.

The real execution plan most likely starts with the movies table if that what the plan shows. However, nested loops do not work independently from each other. There are three tables to be joined, so there will be three for loops nested into each other. The outermost of these for loops will likely be the movies table. If you check out mysql's manual on nested loop optimisation (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/nested-join-optimization.html), towards the end of the documentation you will see a left join on two tables inner joined using comma syntax. Leftmost table is processed first.

Yes, the leftmost table is processed first. But it is joined with the result of the m_cast and p_cast join, not with m_cast alone. The EXPLAIN ANALYZE mentioned by @user1191247 shows the correct processing order. For whatever reason, the visual representation of the plan is different.

Simplified version of your query.  No parenthesis required.  Do the LEFT JOIN conditions at each level from movie to cast to person
select 
      m.title, 
      p_cast.person_name 
   From 
      movie m 
         left join movie_cast m_cast 
            on m.movie_id = m_cast.movie_id 
               join person p_cast 
                  on m_cast.person_id = p_cast.person_id 
                 and p_cast.person_name = 'Brad Pitt'

Now, this result might give you more than you expect as the left-join to the cast will get 1 record for Every cast member, but only if the left-join to the person qualified for 'Brad Pitt' will pull the actual name.  So you would get a list the same moving showing and bunch of null values for the person UNTIL Brad Pitt.
Now, lets add something to see your intent vs what your query is.  So lets see if THIS makes more sense... Is what you are asking really... Get me a list of all movies that Brad Pitt is part of the cast.  Then, from that, get return all cast members of said movies.  If THIS is the case, then I would start with querying all movies associated with Brad Pitt, THEN join again to the cast for others.
select
      m.title,
      castName.Person_Name
   from
      person p
         join movie_cast mcBrad
            p.person_id = mcBrad.person_id
            join movie_cast AllCast
               on mcBrad.movie_id = AllCast.movie_id
               JOIN person castName
                  on AllCast.person_id = castName.person_id
               JOIN movie m
                  on AllCast.movie_id = m.movie_id
   where
      p.person_name = 'Brad Pitt'

So here, we are STARTING with the person filter of Brad Pitt joining to the cast where he is associated.  This will return only one record per movie associated with Brad Pitt.  Now that we have a movie, join AGAIN to the movie cast, but ONLY based on the movie qualified by Brad and getting ALL cast members, but for each individual movie.  Now we have the cast members we can re-join back to the person table for each cast member in the movie.  A second join to the movie table to pull the movie title.
Hopefully a different perspective might be more of what you were intending?

The simplified version would return only the movies in which Brad Pitt acts. However, I want to return all movies. The query itself is not the point. I am not confused about how to write a query. The point is that my query returns all movies only once (complemented with Brad Pitt's name, when applicable), but the query plan led me to believe that each movie should appear multiple times in the result set. Of course, this is not what happens. But why does the query plan look like that?

The graphical representation of the execution plan is not unreasonable, but I can understand why it might be confusing.  If you look at the output of EXPLAIN ANALYZE you will see something like this:
-> Nested loop left join
    -> Table scan on m
    -> Nested loop inner join
        -> Covering index lookup on m_cast using PRIMARY (movie_id=m.movie_id)
        -> Filter: (p_cast.person_name = 'Brad Pitt')
            -> Single-row index lookup on p_cast using PRIMARY (person_id=m_cast.person_id)

Here we can see the left join between Table scan on m and the result of Nested loop inner join. The Nested loop inner join is performed in a loop for each row returned by Table scan on m with m.movie_id as an input to the inner join.
More importantly, this highlights the lack of an index on p_cast.person_name and it is returning all rows from m_cast for the given movie_id, then retrieving the row from p_cast and filtering on person_name.
If you add an index on the person_name you will probably see something like this:
-> Nested loop left join
    -> Table scan on m
    -> Nested loop inner join
        -> Covering index lookup on p_cast using idx_name (person_name='Brad Pitt')
        -> Single-row covering index lookup on m_cast using PRIMARY (movie_id=m.movie_id, person_id=p_cast.person_id)

Here we can see that both movie_id and person_id are used to lookup the row in m_cast.

That's the answer I was looking for. So the tree is not left-side oriented after all. However, it is still able to pipeline the execution since it uses movie_id to lookup rows in m_cast. I wonder why the tree is visually represented as being left-side oriented.
